# Different behavior renaming a file using gsub

Tags: ruby, scripting

I'm unable to correctly rename a directory with pattern matching.
Trying to replace last occurence of `old_name` string with `new`(can be any string) in a filepath:

`./old_name/*/old_name/` ==> `./old_name/*/new/`

If I use a string literal like the below code, I get the desired result:

`dir_name = name.gsub(/(.*)#{old_name}/, '\1new')`

The problem is when I try to replace the literal `'\1new'` with a variable string with interpolation so I can change it to any given name:

`dir_name = name.gsub(/(.*)#{old_name}/, "\1#{any_string}")`

This is what I get:

`./old_name/*/old_name/` ==> `new`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually ending up as `"\u0001new/"` and when you `puts` it, that shows up as `new/`. The reason is because in double quote strings, you need to escape the backslash, so it makes it through to the `gsub` call:

```
dir_name = name.gsub(/(.*)#{old_name}/, "\\1#{any_string}") # => "./old_name/*/new/"
```

Comment: Thank you, we also came up with this:



`dir_name = name.gsub(/(.*)#{old_name}/, '\1' + "#{any_string}")`